# How can I react to touch events in an Editor in Xamarin Forms iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, editor, renderer

I have created my own iOS Editor Renderer and implemented the following two methods to catch touches to the screen:

```
public class EditorExRenderer : EditorRenderer
{
    public EditorExRenderer()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        ...
    }

    public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);

        ...
    }

    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);

        ...
    }
}
```

Neither of them are being called however when I touch the control. All that happens is the cursor is positioned in preparation for text entry. Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming [ExportRendererAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/create#register-the-ivisual-type) is set, check for any gesturerecognizers in the layout(s) around the Editor.

Comment: I added the attribute as described in the link `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(EditorEx), typeof(EditorExRenderer), new[] { typeof(CustomVisual) })]`. Now not only does the touch event not fire, but the editor also doesn't display text. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Please refer to [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/touch/ios-touch-walkthrough) on how to how to respond to touch events in Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: Hi Alexandar, just read the MS as recommended, but they all assume the overriden methods catch the touches. Mine doesn't unfortunately, that's where my problem lies.